# Is Arduino reliable for serious tasks, such as medical machines?

Tags: sensors, robotics

I'm just getting started with Arduino, and it has a LOT of uses, however, I would like to know how reliable is it? Can it be used for medical purposes (Measure vital signs, or to help surgeons perform surgeries), if it depends on the board, which one is the most accurate and reliable?

I know most robotic tasks will rely on the quality of the servo to interpret the Arduino commands, and sensors, and even the coding/logic, but we can replace/recode all of those things, but when it comes to the main board it gets more complicated

Comment: I'd suggest you do background reading specifically on medical device design, then try asking on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange for more detail on best practices for medical robotics. An Arduino is unsuitable for this sort of work (except very simple concept/demo that will never be used in real surgery.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NOT trust using an Arduino for life safety measures (medical purposes).

This discusses the reliability of an Arduino pretty well- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/reliability-of-the-arduino-platform-for-industrial-use

Comment: Althought you should NOT trust Arduino for medical devices, it's perfectly normal to use it to PROTOTYPE your idea and flush it out (without putting human lives in danger).

Comment: What kind of board should I use for such task then?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. Here is a description of the boards https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Boards

Comment: If you are asking what type of board to use in a medical device, you are not remotely qualified to engineer one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton because every good programmer/engineer started by being the best one, not by learning.

Comment: @Dodekeract - if you wish to learn by experiment, you must do so in a different field of applications than *actual* medical devices.  Anyone legitimately prepared to engineer a medical device is going to have a long list of requirements and procedures which every aspect of a design must meet - asking for advice from random internet posters does not remotely figure into it, and indicates that the asker is not qualified to design to this level of reliability requirement.